# Regular expression to accept alphanumeric strings but reject a particular string (.htaccess)

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I am using .htaccess to read URLs

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-\.]+)/?$ profile.php?profileId=$1 [NC,L]
```

the regular expresstion in this line accepts all alphanumeric characters as u know but i want it to reject a particular string - "register"

It accepts :-
`example.com/434` OR `example.com/UserName` OR `example.com/UserName432` formats

so it also accepts `example.com/register` but i want it to reject it. I want this to happen

`example.com/register` => `example.com/login.php?page=register`

And if its possible to reject more strings as `example.com/settings` and more which have similar types of static queries please suggest me ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it to exclude `register`, just add a condition:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/register
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-\.]+)/?$ profile.php?profileId=$1 [NC,L]
```

Or add your other rule before it:

```
RewriteRule ^register/?$ login.php?page=register [L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-\.]+)/?$ profile.php?profileId=$1 [NC,L]
```

For other stuff like settings, you can make explicit rewrites like the register one above.

Comment: thanks @JonLin, you rock mate :) used this :- 
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/register`
`RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-\.]+)/?$ profile.php?profileId=$1 [NC,L]`
`RewriteRule ^register/?$ login.php?page=register [L]`